# Java Primitives range calculation

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

In Java when we declare

```
short number=1024*1024*1024;
```

it will give compile time error but

```
short number=1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

compiles fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: @Raedwald,Erwin,Ivan,Carlos My question is different than the question you mentioned.here the question is not only about literal and run time evaluation of number , but its relates to range of short , in above question even though none of expression is literal, first one gives error, question is that why such behavior happen in compilation? any ways thanks, now I satisfied with below answers.

Comment: good question +1 from my side

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The compiler will, in this case, evaluate the calculation (because it contains only constants) and try to assign the result to the variable. This calculation is done with type `int` and only converted to `short` on assignment, if at all possible.

In your case, the first calculation is too large to fit into a `short` (`1073741824`). The second one will overflow the `int` and end up in a range that `short` supports (`0`). So the assignment works in that case.

Mind you, you probably don't ever want to rely on these things in code.

Comment: We can see this as well by changing one of them to `1024L`, in which case the calculation is done as a `long` and overflow doesn't occur, causing a compile error again.

Comment: @user2169777:- A loss of precision means that you are losing information of the given value.(*The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive).*) In your first case the range of short is crossed(1073741824) and hence you are loosing the information. So you are receiving the error.

Answer (score 11):

You are facing the problem as your number is [wrapping around](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).In the first case it does not wrap around and hence it overflows the range of short. But in the second case it wraps around after the calculationa and hence it comes in the range of short and so you dont have the compile time error.

A loss of precision means that you are losing information of the given value.(*The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive).*) In your first case the range of short is crossed(1073741824) and hence you are loosing the information.

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T.

**EDIT:-**

From **[JLS §3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)**(very correctly mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676375/why-does-int-i-1024-1024-1024-1024-compile-without-error) similar question)

> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger
>   than 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears
>   anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator
>   ([§15.15.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4)).