# Java Integer Max Range multiplication

Tags: java

```
Integer num = 2147483647;
Integer res =  num * num;
System.out.println(res);
```

The Out put for above is 1. Am not sure why. Can someone please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: overflow ........

Comment: Integers have a limited range of 2^32-1... Roughly 2 billion

Comment: 2^32-1 for unsigned integers, (2^32-1)/2 for signed integers

Comment: Let me re-phrase my Question. I know it goes out of bounds for Integer. But Why result is one. What logic ?
I had a look at Integer.java class, but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to demonstrate why result = 1:

```
    long x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    long y = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    long res = x * y;
    System.out.println(Long.toHexString(res));
```

prints

```
3fffffff00000001
```

if we cast res to int we will get 1

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Integer overflow. Java has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive) and your result(res) is beyond Integer max range.

Answer (score 0):

this because of the flag value
      `0: iconst_0`
     `1: istore_1`

As the limit is out of range for `Integer` it will set the flag of `1` for more about how it works [use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676520/2749470)

Answer (score 0):

That's because it overflows the range of integer and even long which is between -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

You should try using BigInteger if that's the case like:

```
String num = "2147483647";
BigInteger mult = new BigInteger(num);
System.out.println(mult.multiply(mult));
```